# C++ specialized template class for a given type list

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

I am writing a kind of sparse matrix implementation, in fact there are 2 distinct implementations: one for light types (i.e. `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int64)` and one for heavy types.

Depending on the `sizeof(T)`, I want to instantiate the corresponding class. I have first tested with a superclass that instantiate the *HeavyType* or the *LightType* implementation, but this requires both light and heavy to inherit from a common virtual *BaseClass*, and the generic call class uses one or the other (not very clean) in this way:

```
template <class T> class Generic{
public:
 Generic(){
   if (sizeof(T) > TRESHOLDVALUE)
    matrix_ = new HeavyType<T>();
   else
    matrix_ = new LightType<T>();
  }
private:
 matrix_ * BaseClass<T>;
};
```

This works, but it is not clean, and the virtualization in *BaseClass* slows down the execution...

I would like to write only one template class, and specialize it for several types, but I wonder: **is it possibile to specialize against a particular value of `sizeof(T)`** (i.e. equivalent to `if (sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int64))`)? or for an array of possible types (`template <> class Matrix<arrayOfPossibleTypes>` )?

I would like to avoid the re-writing of the class for `int`, `bool`, `uint_32`, `int32` , `etc` types.

Does anyone have an idea?

PS: 
Alternatively, I thought to a pre-compiler macro to select *LightType* or *HeavyType* class, but I think it's impossible to use `sizeof()` within a `#if` pre-compiler statement.

Comment: `std::conditional` may help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right that it's not possible to use `sizeof` in a preprocessor directive. And it's not needed, you can specialise on `sizeof(T)` just fine. In fact, you can specialise right on `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int64)`:

```
template <class T>
class Generic{
private:
 MatrixType<T> matrix_;
};

template <class T, bool Light = sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int64)>
struct MatrixType;

template <class T>
struct MatrixType<T, true>
{
  //light matrix
};

template <class T>
struct MatrixType<T, false>
{
  //heavy matrix
};
```

Comment: Thank a looooooot for this hint. Didn't know you could place conditional statements within template type definitions. This works perfectly.

Comment: @Danduk82 To be clear, that conditional statement is a default template argument. It can still be overridden by e.g. doing `MatrixType<int, false>`, but you can hide it in an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this problem is `std::enable_if` (if you're using C++11) or `boost::enable_if` (if you're using an older standard). You can add an extra dummy template parameter to the template:

```
template <class T, typename Enable = void> class Generic;

template <class T>
class Generic<T, typename boost::enable_if_c<sizeof(T) > TRESHOLDVALUE>::type>
{
    // implementation for "heavy" class
    HeavyType<T> matrix_;
};

template <class T>
class Generic<T, typename boost::disable_if_c<sizeof(T) > TRESHOLDVALUE>::type>
{
    // implementation for "light" class
    LightType<T> matrix_;
};
```

This would be best if you actually need to have a different implementation for "light" versus "heavy." If all you're looking to do is change the type of the `matrix_` member, and all the rest of your implementation stays the same, then you could use `std::conditional` (or its Boost equivalent, `boost::mpl::if_c`).

Comment: I'd say `enable_if` is overkill for something where a simple `bool` will do.

Comment: Indeed, specializing on the value of a `bool` would also suffice in this case.

Comment: I prefer not to use external dependencies in this case. Boost is a quite powerfull, but heavy external dependency. ;)

Answer (score 2):

With `std::conditional`, you may do something like:

```
template <class T> class Generic{
public:
    using MatrixType = typename std::conditional<(sizeof(T) > TRESHOLDVALUE), HeavyType<T>, LightType<T>>::type;
 Generic() {}
private:
 MatrixType  matrix_;
};
```